# Add functionality to + button

Tags: angular

I have an input
newFields which is a Map<A,B>  both of which are strings

Now when I enter A and B in the UI and click `+` button then I want A and B to be populated.
Until now, I am able to just enter A and B. When I click `+` button it doesn't get added or populated.

```
private addMessageField(): void {
  if (this.newVariableName.trim() && this.newMessageId.trim()) {
    this.inputList.newFields.set(this.newVariableName, this.newMessageId);
    this.newVariableName = '';
    this.newMessageId = '';
  else {
    console.warn("Both a variable name and a message ID are required.");
  }
}
```

Comment: show how you listen to the `+` button please. And also do you use numpad or `shift`+`=`?

Comment: I think you may need to check for ChangeDetectionStrategy, to make sure the changes of your newFields are detected by Angular and it should rerender for you

Comment: <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="addMessageField()" aria-label="Add new message field">
                    <mat-icon>add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
                </button>